# pybind11 array from 2d vector without copy

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

How can I create a 2d numpy array from a vector of vectors in pybind11?

I'm looking for a way to do this fast & without copy (so move?), and I'd like to do it in a templated fashion.

So far I have:

```
template< typename T >
py::array
array2d_from_vector(std::vector<std::vector<T>> & m) {
    if (m.empty()) return py::array_t<T>();
    std::vector<std::vector<T>>* ptr = new std::vector<std::vector<T>>(std::move(m));
    auto capsule = py::capsule(ptr, [](void* p) {
            delete reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::vector<T>>*>(p);
    });
    return py::array_t<T>(
            {ptr->size(), ptr->at(0).size()},           // shape of array
            {ptr->at(0).size()*sizeof(T), sizeof(T)},   // c-style contiguous strides
            capsule);
}
```

which returns a nonsense 2d array to python with values like:

```
[[ 4.0852747e+30  3.0677226e-41  4.0853762e+30  3.0677226e-41]...
```

So what am I missing! I'm guessing it has to do with the way vectors hold their data, but my values should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: How does `pybind11` store 2d?  `numpy` stores the values in a 1d C array (buffer), and uses shape and strides to view it as 2d.  If your source uses the vector of vectors approach (1 or more layers of nested pointers), you can't use that as a `numpy` data buffer.

Comment: Yea that's what I figured.  so far the fastest I've gotten is with a 'reserve' + insert(vec.end().... call, but was looking to make it a little faster... : /