# pybind11 return std::vector reference pointer only to python

Tags: pybind11

I have written several c++ functions to process large LIDAR point cloud data. Most of these functions produces large std::vector arrays which I need to pass to python. In python the reference of these arrays would be passed to PyOpenGL functions (void pointer parameters). Neither do I manipulate these arrays in python nor I would be sending them back to c++.

```c++
py::dict points_to_mesh(<parameters>) {
    Mesh mesh = generateMesh(<parameters>);
    auto d1 = py::dict(
                    "width"_a=mesh.width,
                    "varray"_a=py::array_t<float>(py::cast(mesh.vn, py::return_value_policy::reference)),
                    "iarray"_a=py::array_t<unsigned int>(py::cast(mesh.indices, py::return_value_policy::reference)));

    return d1;
}
```

The above code is working fine and I'm getting numpy arrays in python but I'm not sure about the approach as it's moving the vector data or copying the actual data? If it's possible to get the vector array as numpy array in python then I'm ok with it provided no copying should be involved. If not, then how do I pass just the reference pointer back to python?
I have found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855664/pybind11-array-from-2d-vector-without-copy) and changed the code.

```c++
template< typename T >
py::array
array_from_vector(std::vector<T> & m) {
    if (m.empty()) return py::array_t<T>();
    std::vector<T>* ptr = new std::vector<T>(std::move(m));
    auto capsule = py::capsule(ptr, [](void* p) {
            delete reinterpret_cast<std::vector<T>*>(p);
    });
    return py::array_t<T>(
            {ptr->size(), ptr->at(0).size()},           // shape of array
            {ptr->at(0).size()*sizeof(T), sizeof(T)},   // c-style contiguous strides
            capsule);
}
```

The code compiles fine but when I use it

```c++
"varray"_a=py::array_from_vector(mesh.vn),
```

I'm getting an error stating:

```c++
error: no matching function for call to 'pybind11::array_t<float>::array_t(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, pybind11::capsule&)'
   23 |     return py::array_t<T>(
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
   24 |             {ptr->size(), ptr->at(0).size()},           // shape of array
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   25 |             {ptr->at(0).size()*sizeof(T), sizeof(T)},   // c-style contiguous strides
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   26 |             capsule);
      |             ~~~~~~~~
```

Another concern involves ownership and life time of data. I'm generating data in plain c++ functions and passing it back to python. Is it possible to solve the requirements without using classes?

Cheers :-)

Comment: There is some info in the [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html?highlight=std%3A%3Avector#making-opaque-types)

Comment: That being said I think that you question could (and should) be improved. You currently give some incomplete code snippets. Rather, a good question should provide a minimal example, that can be tested. Right now I'm not even sure what you are doing in fact

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example